# Printer not printing black ink even though it was just replaced

Tags: printer, hp-deskjet

I am having a problem with a printer. It's an HP Deskjet 3522 with ink cartridges 564. It was out of all types of ink, and we replaced only the black and blue ones (as those were the only ones that got used). The other empty ink cartridges were left in the printer.

**The black ink is not being printed. Anything that should be black is invisible.**

However, blue is being printed. This is not to say black appears as blue, if I set the color of a font to blue then it appears as blue.

I tried resting the printer and I tried only printing in grey scale. I don't think it's possible to print a diagnostics page from the printer, as they usually are in black which the printer is not currently printing. The printer does detect the black and blue ink are full.

Answer (score 0):

When Google-ing the issue, I found two links that could be helpful.

- Within the HP troubleshooting guide for your printer that is found online, I found a link for [Black or Color ink not printing](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Deskjet-3520-e-All-in-One-Printer-series/5162504/model/5231945/document/c03955488/). I would put quotes in for specific items that you should do, but there is a ton of info. Read through these from top to bottom and you should have your issue resolved. The bottom item is to have the printer serviced.
- [This link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/DeskJet-3522-doesn-t-print-black-ink/td-p/2988255) identified that you may need to take it to a service center but also referenced another link (see below)
- [This link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printers-Archive-Read-Only/Black-not-printing/m-p/2926025) was referenced in the previous item, but is not for your printer. The reason I am identifying this is because they do mention the ink vents. You should make sure that these are clear of any clogs. Viewing the link, they will show a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a clean cartridges and align cartridges?  I have had the same issue before and this resolved my case, albeit a different model.  Also, some printers require all cartridges to be full in order to print correctly, but can't vouch for your specific model...

Answer (score 0):

This usually means the print head is clogged and needs to be manually removed and cleaned.  In most HP models, the print head assembly is easily removable once all the cartridges are out.  Some models do not have a removable print head, and some use cartridges that have a print head built in, so check the documentation for your model.

But [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHd-5H2t1s8) are many [guides](http://techin.oureverydaylife.com/manually-clean-hp-printer-printheads-9576.html) on the Internet and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EwToyvRCD4) for cleaning your print heads.